# class 'Former\FormerServiceProvider' not found - Laravel

Tags: php, class, laravel

i'm trying to install the anahkiasen/former package once again but it won't work. The funny thing is, I downloaded it about a weak ago and it was working perfectly. My code if finished and use's this former package. I tried to install a new package a half hour ago and since this the former class isn't found anymore.

Like I mentioned it, it was working perfectly before, but since I did a composer update it doesn't work.

Well I did what they said over here:

https://github.com/formers/former/wiki/Getting-started

first I run this::

```
composer require anahkiasen/former:4.0.*@dev
```

then a composer update

after the update I add this in my config/app.php provider section:

```
Former\FormerServiceProvider::class,
```

and this in the alias section:

```
'Former' => 'Former\Facades\Former',
```

I tried it but it still doesn't work. Just getting

```
Class 'Former\FormerServiceProvider' not found
```

as an output

I removed the package I wanted to install before and found another way.. But the problem with the former class is still there.

Thanks for any help!

Terminal outputs:

```
/var/www/laravel# php composer.phar require anahkiasen/former
```

gives:

```
Using version ^4.0 for anahkiasen/former
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
```

-------- then I added  the provider/alias --- after this:

```
 composer update --no-scripts
```

gives

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
```

composer dump-autoload

gives of course:

```
Generating autoload files

/var/www/laravel/logs# php artisan config:publish anahkiasen/former
```

gives:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Former\FormerServiceProvider' not found in /var/www/laravel/logs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php on line 146


  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
  Class 'Former\FormerServiceProvider' not found
```

note that I changed the directory in the last command

Comment: Remove the facade/service providers before running composer update, or, easiest, run composer update --no-scripts
After that, run composer dump-autoload, and that should work.

Comment: Run this command also:- php artisan config:publish anahkiasen/former

Answer (score 1):

Let's start from the beginning.

Follow below steps:-

1) Run below command in terminal:-
`composer.phar require anahkiasen/former`

2) It'll ask you for the version, type `dev-master`

3) Add Former's service provider to your Laravel application in `app/config/app.php`. In the   providers array add :

```
'Former\FormerServiceProvider',
```

Add then alias Former's main class by adding its facade to the aliases array in the same file :

```
'Former' => 'Former\Facades\Former',
```

4) run `composer update --no-scripts`
After that, run `composer dump-autoload`, and that should work.

If not working then run this command:-

```
php artisan config:publish anahkiasen/former
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: sorry but it did'nt :/ i'm just getting errors in the terminal :/ 

what composer.phar to you mean? my project is in: laravel/project 

but in project is'nt  a composer.phar - just in /laravel

Comment: well I did all what you said, then I changed the provider and alias section - after this I changed from laravel to laravel/project and did a  "composer update --no scripts" and then a composer dump-autoload